# Replace pattern with pattern in vb.net string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to replace `"0A ","0B ",...,"1A ","1B ",...` patterns with `"0A|","0B|",...,"1A|","1B|",...` from string vb.net

I can write individual replace lines like

```
string = string.Replace("0A ", "0A|")
string = string.Replace("0B ", "0B|")
.
.
.
string = string.Replace("0Z ", "0Z|")
```

But, I would have to write too many lines(26*10*2- Two because such scenario occurs twice) and it just doesn't seem to be a good solution. Can someone give me a good regex solution for this?

Comment: Try [`(?<="[a-z\d]+) (?=")` replace with `|` using `IgnoreCase`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22%5ba-f%5cd%5d%2b%29+%28%3f%3d%22%29&i=%220A+%22%2c%220B+%22%2c...%2c%221A+%22%2c%221B+%22%2c...&r=%7c&o=i)

Comment: Show the data structure of template string which you want replace it's letters by your new template please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex.Replace`:

```
result = Regex.Replace(string, "(\d+[A-Z]+) ", "$1|")
```

I used the pattern `\d+[A-Z]+` to represent the text under the assumption that your series of data might see more than one digit/letter.  This seems to be working in the demo below.

### Demo

Comment: Worked, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `\s` **Substitution**: `|`

**Details**:

- `\s` Matches any whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6JklS/1)

VB.NET code:

`Regex.Replace("0A ", "\s", "|") Output: 0A|`